# Order of primary and foreign key, when the primary key is composite

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering about the importance of the order of the sentences

> Primary key (x,y,z)

And

> Foreign key (x,y)

In the example below:

```
create table Angazovanje (
  DatumOd date not null,
  SifraRM numeric not null,
  SifraRadnika numeric not null,
  DatumDo date null,
  primary key (DatumOd, SifraRM, SifraRadnika),
  foreign key (SifraRM) references RadnoMesto (SifraRM),
  foreign key (SifraRadnika) references Zaposleni (SifraRadnika)
);
```

The primary key is set first, then I set the foreign keys. My data works this way. I have been told however that errors may occur and I should put the foreign keys first, and then the primary keys.

May I get an example of how this can cause an error and why? Because I really do not understand what the order has to do with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.  Within a `create table` there is no need to pay attention to the order of such declarations.

Personally, I use synthetic keys -- a simple `identity()` key.  This can be declared inline, rather than as a separate declaration.

In general, you need to be sure that the primary key and table is defined *before* the foreign keys.  However, that is usually at the table level, not within a table.